# Ruby : using self.replace in object to an other object

Tags: ruby, string, replace, typeerror, null

I would to write a method in String that change the current String in an other class, like

```
class String
  def removethis!
    self.replace(nil) if self == "this"
    return self
  end
end
```

but it doesn't work well :

> TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Is it a way to do this ?

Comment: Why do you need this? This is a classic XY problem if I ever saw one.

Comment: I cannot parse your sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change a `String` into `NilClass`. In fact, more generally, you cannot change a class of an object. You can make the contents of a variable that contains a `String` become a `NilClass` instead, but this does not change the `String` itself, nor can you do it as a method on `String`.

Comment: It is what i expected, but i didn't read it anywhere. thanks